# Invert gdalwrap cutline

Tags: gdal, tilemill, gdalwarp

I have a big raster image with medium details, but for some regions I do have far more details as a seperate raster image.

Now I'd like to display both of them in my map that I render with `Tilemill`. 
So now I would need to cut a hole out of the bigger raster (exactly the shape of the small one) file so that both layers will be properly displayed on my map. (Note: I don't display it with an opacity of 100%)

I found that using the `gdalwarp -cutline shape.shp input.tif output.tif` command I can cut a raster. But I need the inverse of that.
Is there a parameter for `gdal` which I am missing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gdal_merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) which will combine the rasters. Have a look at the description of gdal_merge:

> This utility will automatically mosaic a set of images. All the images must be in the same coordinate system and have a matching number of bands, but they may be overlapping, and at different resolutions. In areas of overlap, the last image will be copied over earlier ones.

Comment: Hey Torsten, I now resumed the work on this... But the `gdal_merge` is of no help for us, as the different GeoTiffs have different resolutions
Also increasing the resolution on the low-resolution GeoTiff would make a really really huge raster-file.

So I'd really like to just cut a hole into my geotiff...
Any idea how that works?